# Howto introduce a second menubar in WPF that stretches from top to bottom of screen

Tags: wpf

I want to introduce a second menubar that stretches from top to bottom of screen.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Beige" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <ToggleButton Content="One Button in second menubar"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Seems as if the VerticalAlignment does not what I supposed it does. The StackPanel is minimized around the ToggleButton. How can I have it stretched from top to bottom of the screen?

Comment: `Stretch` or `Rotate`? What do you mean by 'Second' menubar? Can you explain more?

Comment: Can you post the whole XAML of your window?

Comment: What control is your `StackPanel` in? It probably affects how the `StackPanel` is rendered

Comment: @michele: The StackPanel sits in an own class. Basically the class has a Border for dropping a shadow and a Panel for taking the contents.

Comment: @WPF-it: A menubar is what we call a Panel on the right side of the screen. As this panel gets too crowded we want to introduce another panel next to it on the left side. This Panel is triggered by a Button that sits in the "first" (i.e. the right) menubar.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Beige">
        <ToolBar>
            <ToggleButton Content="One Button in second menubar"/>
        </ToolBar>       
    </ToolBarTray>
    <Grid />       
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Now I know what a ToolBarTray is. Actually the question was only about stretching. The DockPanel is not stretched in your example, is it?

Comment: It stretches in the limitations of the parent.

Comment: The DockPanel? It just orders the elements from left to right just like StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" does.

Comment: No, by default the last child fills the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code by putting it in an empty window and it works just like you wanted it to. Make sure it doesn't get size restrictions from it's parent

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Seems as if the parent control restricts it then.